# Getting information on specific fields of length N in a html file using xpath And placing them in some textbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, xpath

I am a novice vb.net programmer
I'm working on a project that takes a set of data from a series
Html file with the same format but with different values ​​I put in some textbox
I already used the search function and file operations I do it
But because the values ​​are different length in some cases I was having Trouble!
After some searching on the internet site and stackoverflow.
I noticed there "xpath"
But I do not know how Getting information on specific fields of length N in a html file using xpath

i need get value of The fields with xpath addres(i i use firebug or inspect element in choreme) and put them to some text box in vb.net
tanx a a lot.

for exp see this code

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Collections.Specialized
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports HtmlAgilityPack
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim doc = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
        Dim strAnswer As String = ""

        doc.LoadHtml("C:\Users\T3AS0FT\Desktop\my_html_file\25696.htm")
        'this number (1)
        Dim a As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode =
          doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[8]/strong")
        RichTextBox1.Text = a.InnerText.ToString ''but dont work!!!!

        'this filed(1)
        Dim b As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode =
      doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[5]/p[2]")
        RichTextBox2.Text = b.InnerText.ToString ''but dont work!!!!


        'this number(2)
        Dim c As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode =
      doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[7]/p")
        RichTextBox3.Text = c.InnerText.ToString ''but dont work!!!!
        ' and ...
        ' i use firebug 
        'this code dont work plz help me
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: i need help !! plz help me ! "asked yesterday"

Comment: I did not understand this part: `specific fields of length N`. Please give an example XML and point to the fields that match your criteria. Try to create a reduced test case, i.e. simplify the XML file structure as much as possible.

Comment: its not importand!   http://www.nippyzip.com/uploads/130828030127-38363.zip    this is my html file i need get value of some filed in some cell(my html file have some table) and put them to my textbox

Comment: Oh HTML, not XML, sorry, my fault. I read XPATH and assumed XML automatically. You generally don't want to deal with HTML using XPATH, because not every HTML is a valid XML. Have a look at [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).